# Connect to remote LDAP server via Guacamole

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-20.04, tomcat9

Ubuntu 20.04
Guacamole 1.3.0
guacamole-auth-ldap-1.3.0

/etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties:
Ldap-hostname:  x.x.x.x
Ldap-port:              389
ldap-user-base-dn: CN=serv,OU=Invis,DC=invis,DC=com

Error:
ERROR o.a.g.a.ldap.LDAPConnectionService - Binding with the LDAP server at "localhost" as user "uid=test@invis.com,CN=serv,OU=Invis,DC=invis,DC=com" failed: ERR_04110_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_SERVER Cannot connect to the server: Connection refused

It is ignoring "Ldap-hostname". Whatever I put for hostname, it is always trying to connect to localhost. It reads other parameters (OU, DC, etc.) but does not read the Ldap-hostname value.

Any idea?

Comment: could you show your hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I just needed to remove the space between "Ldap-hostname:" and the IP address. So, it works with "Ldap-hostname:x.x.x.x".